# Bash Wrong Exit Code

Tags: node.js, bash, circleci

On CircleCI I'm running `npm run test-ci` in my config file.

I have the following scripts in my package.json:

```
"test-ci": ". ./envvars/test.sh && nyc --all mocha --recursive --timeout 10000 && npm run report-coverage-ci",
"report-coverage-ci": "nyc report --reporter=text-lcov > coverage.lcov && codecov -f coverage.json && echo CodeCov Done",
```

Problem is, the Mocha test is failing, yet it still shows on CircleCI that the test is successful.

So if the Mocha test fails, it shouldn't continue onto the section where it reports the code coverage and all of that. But it is continuing onto that section.

You can see the last section of the logs below (I have retracted some sensitive information).

How can I fix this?

```
    ✓ Should work with last key (3760ms)

<--- Last few GCs --->

[8488:0x3743ca0]   140011 ms: Scavenge 1328.2 (1422.9) -> 1327.9 (1423.9) MB, 7.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.151, current mu = 0.118) allocation failure 
[8488:0x3743ca0]   140033 ms: Scavenge 1328.7 (1423.9) -> 1328.3 (1424.4) MB, 15.9 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.151, current mu = 0.118) allocation failure 
[8488:0x3743ca0]   140056 ms: Scavenge 1329.1 (1424.4) -> 1328.8 (1425.4) MB, 7.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.151, current mu = 0.118) allocation failure 


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x1581d2a5c01d]
Security context: 0x18382199e549 <JSObject>
    1: /* anonymous */ [0x74025342ac9] [/home/circleci/repo/node_modules/q/q.js:~846] [pc=0x1581d355b56f](this=0x1ccc2a3a6ac9 <Object map = 0x3093e6868539>,fulfilled=0x1ccc2a3a67c1 <JSFunction query (sfi = 0x35b314d784e9)>,rejected=0x3344031826f1 <undefined>,progressed=0x3344031826f1 <undefined>)
    2: arguments adaptor frame: 1->3
    3: /* anonymous */ [0...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x8c02c0 node::Abort() [/opt/circleci/.nvm/versions/node/v10.9.0/bin/node]
 2: 0x8c030c  [/opt/circleci/.nvm/versions/node/v10.9.0/bin/node]
 3: 0xad15de v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/opt/circleci/.nvm/versions/node/v10.9.0/bin/node]
 4: 0xad1814 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/opt/circleci/.nvm/versions/node/v10.9.0/bin/node]
 5: 0xebe752  [/opt/circleci/.nvm/versions/node/v10.9.0/bin/node]
 6: 0xebe858 v8::internal::Heap::CheckIneffectiveMarkCompact(unsigned long, double) [/opt/circleci/.nvm/versions/node/v10.9.0/bin/node]
 7: 0xeca982 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/opt/circleci/.nvm/versions/node/v10.9.0/bin/node]
 8: 0xecb2b4 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/opt/circleci/.nvm/versions/node/v10.9.0/bin/node]
 9: 0xecdf21 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/opt/circleci/.nvm/versions/node/v10.9.0/bin/node]
10: 0xe97444 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationSpace) [/opt/circleci/.nvm/versions/node/v10.9.0/bin/node]
11: 0x1136d5e v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInNewSpace(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/opt/circleci/.nvm/versions/node/v10.9.0/bin/node]
12: 0x1581d2a5c01d 
-----------------------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File                                     |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------------------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files                                |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |                   |
 repo                                    |        0 |        0 |      100 |        0 |                   |
  create_tables.js                       |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |                   |
-----------------------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|

> Project@1.0.0 report-coverage-ci /home/circleci/repo
> nyc report --reporter=text-lcov > coverage.lcov && codecov -f coverage.json && echo CodeCov Done

  _____          _  
 / ____|        | |  
| |     ___   __| | ___  ___ _____   __  
| |    / _ \ / _` |/ _ \/ __/ _ \ \ / /  
| |___| (_) | (_| |  __/ (_| (_) \ V /  
 \_____\___/ \__,_|\___|\___\___/ \_/  
                                v3.1.0
==> Detecting CI Provider
    Circle CI Detected
==> Configuration: 
    Endpoint: https://codecov.io
{ commit: '',
  branch: 'master',
  package: 'node-v3.1.0' }
==> Building file structure
==> Generating gcov reports (skip via --disable=gcov)
    $ find /home/circleci/repo -type f -name '*.gcno'  -exec gcov  {} +
==> Targeting specific file
    X Failed to read file at /home/circleci/repo/coverage.json
==> Uploading reports
    Success!
    View report at: https://codecov.io/github/rrainn/package/commit/
CodeCov Done
```

Comment: were you ever able to figure out a fix for this? we're running into it now

Comment: @gnauhnoj I don't believe so. Normally if I solve it, I post an answer to my own question. Tho it's been a while since this question was asked so I'm not 100% sure. My CI infrastructure has changed quite a bit since this question was asked so it hasn't been something I've run into recently.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of bash, your command line is correct. The problem seems to be that the command `nyc --all mocha --recursive --timeout 10000` is failing but finishing execution with the zero exit code. So the `&&` operator considers it's ok to go to the next command.

The root cause seems to be in mocha, or more specifically in node. There is a github issue posted:
[Mocha exits with 0 exit code with failing tests #2713](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/2713)

From the issue comments it seems that it's fixed in node 8.10.

Comment: I'm running Node.js version 10.12

Comment: Would adding the check coverage argument change anything then?`nyc --all mocha --recursive --timeout 10000 --check-coverage`. I don't know any of node.js, nyc or mocha, just looking at their code and trying to sort it this way. From a strict bash perspective - my area of expertise -, everything is correct.